# Raise the Elephant not working with Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, freeze

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. This was not a fresh install, but rather an upgrade. My question regards a keystroke combination that I would use when the browser would freeze the desktop. To restart the computer I would Raise the Elephant, that is, holding  <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>SysRq</kbd> while I entered the key sequence R E I S U B. This used to work until I upgraded. Now it does not work when the system is frozen (It will still restart the computer when the screen is not frozen). Why?